# JavaFX-samples-2.2.21 DataApp's DataAppServer launch issue

Tags: java, javafx-2

I download the latest JDK and samples. I am trying to run the above JavaFX sample program but its DataAppServer always give me error.

The database and glassfish server are running properly. I can run the DataAppClient without any issues. I can also run other samples via IE browser by clicking the existing html files.

The DataAppServer is the same as DataAppClient but the client is running as a web service and launched in the IE browser.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I am using the latest NetBeans IDE. I didn't change anything on the sample. I checked my machine Java setting, the Java is enable.

This is the first warning when I run the DataAppServer:

[image]

Then, I check the checkBox and click the Run button. The following page shows up:

[image]

The details of the error is this:

[image]

Anything I should do to make it works for me?

**EDIT:**

I noticed there are some error on the GlassFish Server, which is the latest v3.1.2:

```
SEVERE: Exception while visiting com/sun/gjc/spi/base/datastructure/Cache.class of size 450
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.TypesImpl.getType(TypesImpl.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor.visit(ModelClassVisitor.java:119)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:363)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.JarArchive.onSelectedEntries(JarArchive.java:125)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.onSelectedEntries(DirectoryArchive.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and

```
SEVERE: Thu Jun 13 08:56:54 EDT 2013 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Access is denied)

SEVERE: Thu Jun 13 08:56:54 EDT 2013 Thread[main,5,main] Ignored duplicate property derby.module.dataDictionary in jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1.2.2/javadb/lib/derby.jar!/org/apache/derby/modules.properties

SEVERE: Thu Jun 13 08:56:54 EDT 2013 Thread[main,5,main] Ignored duplicate property derby.module.lockManagerJ1 in jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1.2.2/javadb/lib/derby.jar!/org/apache/derby/modules.properties

SEVERE: Thu Jun 13 08:56:54 EDT 2013 Thread[main,5,main] Ignored duplicate property derby.env.classes.dvfJ2 in jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.1.2.2/javadb/lib/derby.jar!/org/apache/derby/modules.properties
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [sign](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html) the DataApp client application in order to provide the application with the permissions it requires to run.

To perform the signing in NetBeans, open the DataApp client project, right click on the project and choose "Properties", click the "Request unrestricted access (Enable signing)" checkbox.

[image: sign]

Rebuild your DataApp client project and try running it.  You will still get a warning when you run the application from a browser or webstart deployment, (it will be a different one indicating that the publisher used a self-signed certificate), however the application should now have all the permissions required to run after clicking through the warning.

Further details about signing applications and JavaFX are provided in the [JavaFX deployment documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFBH).

In particular, the DataApp client makes use of fxml.  Applications deployed in a sandboxed environment (such as a browser or webstart), must be signed to allow them to work (at least in JavaFX 2.2, and likely in later JavaFX releases as well).  See the issue tracker reference [RT-23622 JavaFX applications with FXML fail while running on browser](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23622) for more information on this.

Comment: Yes, I tried that before and tried again. It still the same. But I noted there are Severe errors on GlassFish Server. I don't know if it is related. I have added the errors on my question.

Comment: I have an issue with this SDK sample, it's described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033117/netbeans-8-1-and-jersey-2

Comment: @ManKeer it is probably not worthwhile trying to get the DataApp sample up and running anymore.  Oracle stopped supporting it, so it is coded to old APIs that are now obsolete.