# Netbeans 8.1 and Jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have the latest version of netbeans and I'm trying to run the DataAppClient Sample which comes with JavaFX SDK Samples, DataAppClient imports the following packages :

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException;
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
```

Netbeans shows an error sign on each of these packages says "package doesn't exist". it's clear that all these packages related to the Jersey, and all the Jersey libraries are included in the project libraries "Jersey 2.5.1 (JAX-RS RI) - ******"

I tried many of the solutions published on the net, but no one solve my issue.

How can I solve it.....

Comment: netbeans 8.0.2 is not the latest version of netbeans

Comment: you're right, I installed netbeans 8.1 and still the same issue

Comment: The example is using a Jersey 1.x client. The APIs have changed in Jersey 2.x. If you want to use the code as is, then you need the Jersey 1.x client jars. Not sure the exact jars, but if you using Maven, I can help you, other wise you will need to search for the jars yourself. Or learn to use the [Jersey 2.x Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) and try to port the code

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet for your suggestion, I have downloaded jersey 1.19 and I have added it to the project libraries, and finally it's built successfully, but now it can't deployed on the glassfish server

Comment: Are you getting NoSuchMethodErrors?

Comment: This is GlassFish Server output:

Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /DataAppServer
Info:   /file:/C:/Users/ajc5518/Desktop/Java SDK Samples/javafx-samples-2.2.80/src/DataApp/DataAppServer/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/DataAppLibrary.jar_DataAppLibraryPU logout successful
Info:   [1] timers deleted for id: 95560696515919872
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer